# Sketch the complex set

Tags: complex-numbers

Sketch the set of complex numbers $\{z : |\bar z−1+i|<1\}$
Please note that the z in the inequality is CONJUGATED.

I did one where the z was not conjugated and ended up getting a circle and filling in the respective space. I am unsure of what a conjugate z does to getting the new graph.

Comment: I don't see any conjugation??? Note that $|\bar{z} -a| <  r$ is equivalent to $|z-\bar{a}| < r$ since $|w| = |\bar{w}|$.

Comment: do you mean $\{z:|\overline{z}-1+i|<1\}$?

Comment: yes that's what I meant I just wasn't sure how to type it into my computer sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your set is$$\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\middle|\,\left|\overline z-1+i\right|<1\right\},$$then, since you know that $\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\middle|\,\left|z-1+i\right|<1\right\}$ is the open disk centered at $1-i$ with radius $1$, your set is its conjugate, that is, it is the open disk centered at $1+i$ with radius $1$.

Comment: ok this is what I was expecting thank you! and also the circle should be expressed as a dotted line correct?

Comment: @stacy That is how it is usually represented, yes.